# My ionicModal won't show when called upon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

So I have a simple modal trying to be shown when I press a button. But it won't show up. Here is my code (straight from the docs basically).

```js
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/addUser.html', {
      scope: $scope,
      animation: 'slide-in-up'
    }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
    });
    $scope.openModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.show();
    };
    $scope.closeModal = function() {
      $scope.modal.hide();
    };
    
$scope.myEvent = function() {
      var hideSheet = $ionicActionSheet.show({
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Add User'
        }],
        //destructiveText: 'Delete',
        titleText: 'Options',
        cancelText: 'Cancel',
        cancel: function() {
          // add cancel code..
          hideSheet();
        },
        buttonClicked: function(index) {
          hideSheet();
          $scope.openModal();
        }
      });
    }
```

```html
<script id="addUser.html" type="text/ng-template">
  <ion-modal-view>
    <ion-header-bar>
      <h1 class="title">My Modal title</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content>
      Hello!
    </ion-content>
  </ion-modal-view>
</script>
```

When I click the Add User button, the sheet then closes, but no modal is shown. I cannot figure out why. I have done my research and this is the most basic example that is shown everywhere, yet I can't get it to work. Please, any help will be great.

Comment: Have you looked at the debugging console? My guess is `$scope.modal` is `undefined`...

Comment: what is `myEvent` ? why are you not using `ng-click="openModal()"` ?

Comment: `myEvent` opens up the actionSheet which shows the Add User button which when clicked needs to show the modal. `$scope.modal` is definitely not `undefined`.